# How can I show long titles in a short drop-down list button?

Tags: labels, text, truncation

I have a dropdown button which will display under it a list of sections for an online e-learning course.

The button works fine for short titles but this website is known for having titles that can go up to a sentence or more.

Is there any particularly good methods of showing a longer title here rather than just using an ellipses?

[image: Contents Drop Down]

So the title goes where it currently says Contents however the titles can get a lot longer.

Answer (score 0):

I see there being two obvious solutions here:

1) You can just wrap it so it'll go to the next line (not very pretty probably)

2) Have a tooltip that show the full title on hover (this is done common enough that your user may expect this to happen).